# How to plot overlaid cubes

Tags: r, 3d

How to plot `n` overlaid cubes? For example,

```
#cube 1
x1 <- c(0,1,1,0,0,  1,1,1,1,1,  1,1,0,0,1,  0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,1,0,0,  0,1,1,0,0) 
y1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,  1,0,0,1,1,  0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,1,0, 1,1,0,0,1,  1,1,0,0,1)
z1 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,  0,0,1,1,0,  0,1,1,0,0,  0,1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,1)


#cube 2
x2 <- .5*c(0,1,1,0,0,  1,1,1,1,1,  1,1,0,0,1,  0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,1,0,0,  0,1,1,0,0) 
y2 <- .5*c(1,1,1,1,1,  1,0,0,1,1,  0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,1,0, 1,1,0,0,1,  1,1,0,0,1)
z2 <- .5*c(0,0,1,1,0,  0,0,1,1,0,  0,1,1,0,0,  0,1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,1)

#cube 3
x3 <- .3*c(0,1,1,0,0,  1,1,1,1,1,  1,1,0,0,1,  0,0,0,0,0, 0,1,1,0,0,  0,1,1,0,0) 
y3 <- .3*c(1,1,1,1,1,  1,0,0,1,1,  0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,1,0, 1,1,0,0,1,  1,1,0,0,1)
z3 <- .3*c(0,0,1,1,0,  0,0,1,1,0,  0,1,1,0,0,  0,1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,1)
```

Any tip I thank!

## I edited the points!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `plot3d` from `rgl` to do this:

```
library(rgl)
#first cube
plot3d(x1, y1, z1, type="p", col="red", xlab="x", 
       ylab="y", zlab="z", site=5, lwd=15)
#second cube (notice add=TRUE to overlay)
plot3d(x2, y2, z2, type="p", col="blue", xlab="x", 
       ylab="y", zlab="z", site=5, lwd=15, add=TRUE)
#third cube (notice add=TRUE to overlay)
plot3d(x3, y3, z3, type="p", col="green", xlab="x", 
       ylab="y", zlab="z", site=5, lwd=15, add=TRUE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I edited the points. Your answer is perfect. Can you edit your figure? Then, the answer will be complete.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the figure and added some comments to make it clear for other users with the same question.

Comment: The cube can be shown modifying the parameter `type = "p"` for `type = "l"`.